# Dynamically added labels disappear in runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I add labels to my form programmatically, but they disappear, except last one. I'm sure that given location to them is appropriate. But when the second label appears, first disappears, or when third label appears, second disappears.

Here is my code:

```
Label[] lenlab = new Label[255];

Label lab = new Label();
lab.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
lab.ForeColor = Color.White;
lab.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
lab.AutoSize = true;

lenlab[1] = lab;
lenlab[1].Location = new Point(50, panel1.Location.Y + panel1.Height + 20);
lenlab[1].Text = c[1];
this.Controls.Add(lenlab[1]);

for (int i = 2; i < c.Count; i++) 
{
    lenlab[i] = lab;
    lenlab[i].Location = new Point(lenlab[i - 1].Location.X + lenlab[i -1].Width + 40, lenlab[i - 1].Location.Y);
    lenlab[i].Text = " + " + c[i];
    this.Controls.Add(lenlab[i]);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you only __create__ one Label. You add severaly reference to that same one Label but there is only one. Count the `new` calls! - Also we'd rather see the real code; this doesn't compile..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm trying. @TaW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is causing every position in your array to have a reference to the same `Label` you created originally, outside the loop, which means all you're doing is changing the position and text of the *same* `Label` inside your loop.

```
lenlab[i] = lab;
```

The behavior you're seeing is due to the fact that you can only add a particular control to `this.Controls` once, so the effect is that you see the *same* label changing position.

Here's the portion of the `Add()` method that checks whether the control you're adding already has a parent, and if it does, then it removes it from it's current parent before adding it to the new one. So every time you call `this.Controls.Add()` with the same `Label`, it removes it from the `Form` and then adds it again.

```
// Remove the new control from its old parent (if any)
if (value.parent != null) {
    value.parent.Controls.Remove(value);
}
```

Instead, create a new `Label` inside your `for` loop:

```
lenlab[i] = new Label();
```

There are controls that can help you layout controls without the need to calculate a new position each time. In particular, read up on the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Your recommendation will help me so much. Thank you again! @Grant Winney

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing there is basically create **one** `Label`, change it several times, and attach it several times to the page. What you end up having on the page is the last version of the Label being added once, which is the expected behavior.

If you want to add several labels, you need to `new` each of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Great! @Mihai Dinculescu